# How to make a shrinking black box in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a shrinking black box in pygame where the corner of the black box stays at (0,0). I coded but I really can not find anything wrong with my code, but it still does not work.

```py
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(250, 10)
import pygame
pygame.init()
SIZE = (650, 650)   
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)


RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (0,0, 650, 650))

while True:
    x = 650
    y = 650
    if x >= 1:
        x-1
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0,0, x, y))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(100)  

pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.wait(5000)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to clear the display in every frame. If you do not clear the display, then the smaller box is drawn on top of the bigger box from the last frame and the shrink effect is not visible.
Furthermore `x` and  `y` have to be initialized before the application loop and `x-1` has no effect at all. If you want  to decrement a variable, then you have to use the `-=` operator (`x -= 1`).
Finally I recommend to handle the events and to implement the `pygame.QUIT` event:

```py
x = 650
y = 650

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if x >= 1:
        x -= 1

        # draw BLACK background
        screen.fill(BLACK)

        # draw RED box
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (0,0, x, y))

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(100)
```

Note, the color of the background is `BLACK` and the color of the box is `RED`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to make the black box shrink faster but just as smooth though? I feel like the pacing is a bit slow.

Comment: @conyieie Reduce the delay, e.g.: `pygame.time.wait(10)`

Comment: Also can I ask what  run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False                means and what I can replace it with ?

Comment: @conyieie It handel the `pygamae.QUIT` event, as I mentioned in the answer. You can replace it by `while True:`, but the the close button of thew window won't work any more.